# SQL Stored Proc; using ISNULL(db1.value, db2.value) performance issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

Attempting to debug a stored proc to figure out why it never ends(waited > 2min). The proc has 3 left joins and then at the bottom is an ISNULL that is checking a db for a value to be null then replacing it with a value from a 2nd db. The way I found out what the problem was was to comment out the joins and clauses then slowly add the joins in then the clauses. After adding in the last clause it started loading for too long.
My question is, is there a way to fix this that doesn't involve indexing? If possible, could you also explain why this is causing the large loading times?

```
 FROM X x WITH (NOLOCK)
   LEFT JOIN A a WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON a.a1 = x.x1
   LEFT JOIN B b WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON b.b1 = a.a1 AND LEFT(a.a2, 2) = '--' AND a.a2 NOT IN ('---')
   LEFT JOIN C c WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON c.c1 = a.a1 AND LEFT(a.a2, 2) <> '--' AND a.a2 NOT IN ('---', '---', '--', '--', '--')
   WHERE ISNULL(x.x3, 0) <> 1     
   AND CASE
            WHEN x.x2 IN ('--', '---', '---') THEN '----'
            WHEN x.x2 IN ('---') THEN x.x2
            END = @2
   AND ISNULL(b.b2, c.c2 + c.c3) LIKE  @3
```

Note: I replaced most values with dummy variables but they are consistent.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: So performance is fine up though the line `ISNULL(b.b2, c.c2 + c.c3) LIKE  @3`? or performance suffers at line `ISNULL(x.x3, 0) <> 1 ` ? The subject and question imply the last one in your where clause, but not sure...  Logically if b.b2 is null... c.c2+c.c3 could also be null. adding nulls results in null but then comparing a null like @3 would be problematic. perhaps `ISNULL(b.b2, coalesce(c.c2,'') + coalesce(c.c3,''))` if string or `ISNULL(b.b2, coalesce(c.c2,0) + coalesce(c.c3,0))` if c c.c2 and c.c3 are numeric.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity; b.b2, c.c2, c.c3 are strings. Yes the problem occurs right at ISNULL(b.b2....) Either b2 will be null or c2 and c3 will be null but not both b2 and c2/c3. Also @3 is a VARCHAR(15) if that helps any. Thanks for answering also.

Comment: Could you give an example of what would be in @3 and c.c2 and c.c3 when they would be 'realized'  I'm curious if the like has %'s or what the SQL would would like prior to execution. Also, an screenshot of the execution plan from SQL server may help isolate where the bottleneck is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is called, SARGability, SQL Server can't use indexes when you have functions used in where clause or joins.

You could replace this `ISNULL(x.x3, 0) <> 1` just with `x.x3 <> 1` since nulls won't match that anyhow.

For the second isnull: `ISNULL(b.b2, c.c2 + c.c3) LIKE  @3`, if you know what will be in c2 in that case, you could replace with union or union all with something like this:

```
select ...
   WHERE ISNULL(x.x3, 0) <> 1     
   AND CASE
            WHEN x.x2 IN ('--', '---', '---') THEN '----'
            WHEN x.x2 IN ('---') THEN x.x2
            END = @2
   AND b.b2 LIKE  @3

union all

select ...
   WHERE ISNULL(x.x3, 0) <> 1     
   AND CASE
            WHEN x.x2 IN ('--', '---', '---') THEN '----'
            WHEN x.x2 IN ('---') THEN x.x2
            END = @2
   AND b.b2 is NULL and c.c2 = @startof3 and c.c3 like @endof3
```

Also, the joins might perform better if you change `LEFT(a.a2, 2) = '--'` into `a.a2 like '--%'` because that is SARGable.